# How to replace single quote with double quotes in json apex

Tags: apex, json

```
   [
    {'InvoiceNumber':'DRAFT-0000007',
     'ErrorDescription':'2130701-Customer Account Number doesn't exist in SAGE metadata'},
    {'InvoiceNumber':'DRAFT-0000166',
     'ErrorDescription':'1778001-Customer Account Number doesn't exist in SAGE metadata'},
    {'InvoiceNumber':'DRAFT-0000000',
     'ErrorDescription':'2281401-Customer Account Number doesn't exist in SAGE metadata'}
    ]
```

Comment: Functionally, that is not JSON, and it's not even internally consistent because it does not escape internal quotes. How did you end up with this text string? You should fix whatever is sending you this payload rather than trying to un-break a broken format.

Comment: Actually the external system is sending this data only, so I have to do this in correct format in order to parse the json data.

Comment: Please do not post new questions in the comments. Take a look at [ask], please, and open a new post.

Comment: Actually I am not able to ask questions as it has reached the limit of 3

Comment: Please read [this help article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This payload is not JSON and is not parseable without ugly and fragile workarounds. This is because it *does not escape its field delimiter*. Field values contain literal single quotes, meaning that any parser cannot distinguish between the end of a field value and the field's content.

Replacing single quotes with double quotes will not work. This still won't be valid JSON. At best you'd have to apply some heuristic like replacing quotes that are next to object markers (`{`, `}`), but that is fragile and not the way a production system should be working.

Your remote system, if it is really sending you this literal payload and this hasn't been processed through some other mechanism that would replace quotes or remove escape characters, is broken. If you are rendering this payload through something else that would change the actual characters being sent, you need to not do that because you may be damaging the content.

Emphasis on this last point: you need to be looking at the raw bytes the remote system is sending you. If this is the output of a `System.debug()` statement, we may be being deceived about the actual input data.

Comment: But I don't have any choice left.. I will have to design a method where it should brilliantly convert the single quotes with double quotes without changing the sentences like (don't to don"t).

Comment: @sonam This is a great opportunity for you to go to your technical lead and say "This is a risk to the project; we need to make sure this data is sent in a consistent and stable format."

Comment: Agree, sonam, the communication between two systems should happen according to defined data exchange or representation formats unless this is a user input for a ML project. In this case JSON. You should be able to do it using a parser created via stack and an algorithm but this will need constant updating and will be technical debt on the team.